# Android pick limited number of images from gallery

Tags: android

I am using this piece of code to get multiple images from gallery:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_image)), GALLERY_CODE);
```

But how do I restrict the number of images that can be picked? For example, I only want the user to pick at most 9 images.

Comment: as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33604995/7948109) it is not possible, you have manually check the return value or like some other Apps you can create your own imagePicker like WhatsApp show's it's own image picker instead of Gallery

Comment: I don't think you can do that by launching `intents` instead I believe you will have to load images from gallery into your app and then you can code logic for allowing user to select max number of images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [maximum image selection limit from gallery Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604951/maximum-image-selection-limit-from-gallery-android)