# how I can select multiple images from gallery in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my code:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
```

I tried using a set of libraries, but I could not add a limit that makes the user select a maximum of 10 images

Comment: Please, check this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585815/select-multiple-images-from-android-gallery).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select multiple images from android gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585815/select-multiple-images-from-android-gallery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you need to understand a few things. Firstly, if you want to limit the number of items user can pick from intent don't use default method like you used. Instead create an activity then customize it. Secondly, If you want to use default system, let user select as much as user wants but take only those which you want from the **ActivityResultLauncher**.

```
     Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
```

Use this above code in onClick method and

```
      ArrayList<Uri> files;
    someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (null != result.getData()) {
                        files = new ArrayList<>();
                        if (null != result.getData().getClipData()) {
                            int count = result.getData().getClipData().getItemCount();
                            if (count >= 10) {
                                showSweetAlertError(this, "Error", "Maximum 10 photo.");
                            }
                            for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(count, 10); i++) {
                                Uri uri = result.getData().getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                                files.add(uri);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Uri uri = result.getData().getData();
                            files.add(uri);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Create `ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher` globally
then in onCreate write the above code. This should work.

**Note:**  If user selects a single photo then `result.getData().getData()` code will be executed. If user select multiple photos then `result.getData().getClipData()` code will be executed. So the if statement is important.

Comment: check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54573243/8724629